# how to iterate DOM ol and save its li values to array using jquery

Tags: jquery

I would like to iterate ol and save all li into array

```
<ol id="sortableAvailable">
  <li id="1"><a href="" >Foo 1</a></li>
  <li id="2"><a href="" >Foo 2</a></li>
  <li id="3"><a href="" >Foo 3</a></li>
  <li id="4"><a href="" >Foo 4</a></li>
</ol>
```

js should be somthing like this:

```
var testInfoList = {};
testInfoList.ConfiguredTests = [];    


/* some iteration that do the following */
testInfoList.ConfiguredTests.push({
    ID: /*here i want the ID*/,
    Value: /*here i want the value*/
});
```

Comment: $("#sortableAvailable li").each(function() { ... });

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/):

```
testInfoList.ConfiguredTests = = $("#sortableAvailable li").map(function() {
    return { ID:this.id, Value:$(this).find("a").text() };
}).get();
```

`map` will iterate over your elements (selected finding all the `li`s inside your list) and apply a function to each of them. The result will be a jQuery object, which can be extracted back to an array using `.get()`.

I'm assuming by "Value" you mean the text inside the links; if you want something else, you can extract it from the current element (`this` is the DOM element, `$(this)` wraps it in a jQuery object).

Answer (score 1):

```
var myarray = [];    

$("ol li").each(function(){
    myarray.push({
                   ID: $(this).attr('id'),
                   Value: $(this).html()
                 });
});
```